# How to add field of six digits with static value 1

Tags: java, android

Based on this example, they convert number to string format but i like to change 0 to 1 in the first digit.

Example:

```
String.format("%06d", num)
```

- '0' The gaps are filled with 0.
- '6' The result has a size of 6.
- 'd' The result is formatted as a decimal integer.

response:

```
000008
000078
```

What i want to attain:

```
100008
100078
```

Thankyou.

Comment: `"1" + String.format("%05d", num)` ?

Comment: Thankyou got it, but it will iterate if i put it inside the format string?

Comment: java code, i think it's working now. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

As you want **a static 6th digit** set to `1`, I would simply ignore the last digit thanks to a modulus `100,000` and print `1` instead as next:

```
String.format("1%05d", num % 100_000)
```

*Example:*

```
System.out.println(String.format("1%05d", 8 % 100_000));
System.out.println(String.format("1%05d", 78 % 100_000));
System.out.println(String.format("1%05d", 654_321 % 100_000));
```

*Output:*

```
100008
100078
154321
```

If you know that the 6th digit is always `0`, you can simply use `String.format("1%05d", num)`.